# Real Quadratic Equation With Complex Roots

Tags: complex-numbers, roots, quadratics

My textbook(Year 12 Cambridge Mathematics Extension 2) provides me with the formula in box 11:
[image]

This is for quadratic equations with real coefficients. However, the textbook then asks me to use box 11 for:

[image]

Every quadratic in the question has at least one complex coefficient. How can I use this method in this case? Am I missing something or has the textbook made an error? Thanks to anyone who can help:)

Comment: Hi! You are right, the textbook is wrong (may be just a wrong number of box?)

Comment: @AnneBauval What do you mean? Is the textbook wrong in asking me this?

Comment: Look for another box number.  Maybe the numbers are mixed up.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks for the response! The textbook is Year 12 Cambridge Mathematics Extension 2.

Comment: Please interpolate that information into your opening sentence.  Publishers often provide errata pages in the support of textbooks.